# grinding down garage floor

Tags: cement

I have to grind down my garage floor. Can I use a hand held grinder with a diamond blade? I saw a grinder for $80.00, 11 amps 4 1/2, I think might work. I don't know where to rent one.

Comment: To put it mildly a hand held grinder would not be the preferred tool for grinding an entire floor. Look into renting a floor sander or grinder.

Comment: Probably shouldn't ask, but **why** are you grinding the entire floor? (I fear that you might be asking the wrong question...)

Comment: Not sure of your currency, but an $80 grinder doesn't sound high-end.  It may not have the endurance to complete the job.   Rent a suitable tool and save your knees.